# В матрице записать строку в столбец

Tags: java, c#, c++

Предположим, что у нас есть матрица 4 на 4, на главной диагонали стоят 0:

```
  0 1 2 3

  0 0 4 5

  0 0 0 6

  0 0 0 0
```

Надо записать строку в столбец так, чтоб у нас получилась симметричная матрица.

```
 0 1 2 3

 1 0 4 5

 2 4 0 6

 3 5 6 0
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(j = i+1; j < N; ++j)
            a[j][i] = a[i][j];` - вам это нужно?...

Comment: Вообще да, но оно не работает , если в матрице стоят 0

Comment: Т.е. если мы задаем массив размерности 4 на 4 и записываем в него только числа больше 0.               mas[0][1]= 1;mas[0][2]= 2;
        mas[0][3]= 3;
        mas[1][2]= 4; и т.д.

Comment: Да работает, работает... Если вам нужно переписать верхний треугольник в нижний. Если нужно что-то иное - давайте точный ТЗ, без него результат всегда один - ХЗ...

Comment: Как работает, если не работает) У меня при выводе матрицы c 0 - вообще не отображается она

Comment: Ну значит покажите код.

Comment: Так **что** не работает? Мой совет или **ваша** программа? Откуда же мне знать, что вы там написали...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 4;
    int m = 4;
    int a[n][m] = {{0,1,2,3},
                   {0,0,4,5},
                   {0,0,0,6},
                   {0,0,0,0}};
    int b[n][m];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            if(i>j){
                b[i][j] = a[j][i];
            }else{
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, если даже записать матрицу частично!